Alien infection & possible possesion
Recent movie (from 2010 or newer) where people who are infected turn into brainwashed ideal citizens. There's a scene where waiters at a conference attempt to infect occupants with disease by upchucking in a punch bowl. This woman tries to escape the city (I believe N.Y.) and she has a young boy with her. Once infected, you turn into them when you fall asleep.

Any other plot details that may help identification? Anything else you remember?

piece of cake, its The Invasion.

You're likely looking for The Invasion, Oliver Hirschbiegel's 2007 adaptation of Jack Finney's The Body Snatchers (previously adapted in 1956, 1978 (the best IMHO) and 1993), starring Nicole Kidman:

While returning to Earth, the space shuttle explodes and the fragments bring an alien virus that recodes the human DNA. In Washington, the psychiatrist Carol Bennell observes the modification of the behavior of one of her clients first, then in her former husband and finally in the population in general. Together with her friend Dr. Ben Driscoll the researcher Dr. Stephen Galeano, they discover that the extraterrestrial epidemic affects human beings while sleeping and that her son Ollie, who had chickenpox when he was a baby, is immune to the disease and may save mankind from the outbreak.

And in one scene:

One gross moment shows alien-infected waiters vomiting into coffee pots and then later serving the resulting liquid.

